# Passing props to props.children, receiving wrong props

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

App.js is the wrapper for my page, it's the layout enclosing the routes. Initially my routes were in App.js, but I want them in a higher order component so I can create routes which arent wrapped by App.

This is my current setup:

> index.js

```
ReactDom.render(
  <Provider>
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Route path='/' [...] />  // <-- Component which is NOT wrapped in App
      <App>
        <Route path='/about' component={About} /> // <-- I want About to receive the props from App
      </App>
    </BrowserRouter>
  </Provider>
);
```

My App.js holds the Header, Sidebar and Footer component. App.js is the component I am exporting with connect(), I am mapping my redux state and actions with mapStateToProps and mapDispatchToPros in App.js

To pass the props down to, say, About, I tried different things with the same result, one of them being:

> App.js

```
{React.cloneElement(this.props.children, {...this.props})}
```

However, the props I receive in About are completely different from the ones I am passing down. They are like this: (json)

{"match": {"path":"/about", "url": "/about", "isExact":true [...]}

So I am guessing those props come from the index.js, where my routes are. But how do I achieve what I am trying to do? Index.js is the component I am rendering the whole Application in. I am not exporting index.js.

Should I move the redux related stuff like mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps, connect(), ... to index.js? Or is there another solution?

Thanks!

Comment: are you want to use props like (dispatch) on About component ?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, yes. I need dispatches (actions) and other props in my about component.

Comment: Could you just export `About` with `connect`,  same as `App`?

Comment: you need to use`connect`  in (About) component

Comment: Thank you so much. That works, but is it really the recommended way? So I'd have to use connect in every component, basically. Is there no way I only use connect in one higher order component and just pass the state as props down?